# How can I change the local host url from http://localhost:8888 to something custom

Tags: database, url, mamp

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution to my issue. I'm in the process of setting up a local Craft 3 site and have a question regarding the URL setup. When I originally installed Craft I did a manual install (downloaded Craft 3 from the Craft site) and used terminal and MAMP and used the manual MAMP default ports (which was the direction in the video tutorial I watched). I did not install using Composer for I was having issues. I'm on a Mac.

I edited my .env file to the settings below after creating my database in phpMyAdmin to the settings I entered:

```
# Database Configuration
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_SERVER=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=craftdatabase
DB_USER=craftuser
DB_PASSWORD=Sundancer290
DB_SCHEMA=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=

# The URI segment that tells Craft to load the control panel
CP_TRIGGER=admin

PRIMARY_SITE_URL=http://localhost:8888/
```

My base URL setting in Craft under settings/sites is $PRIMARY_SITE_URL.

When I click the visit webpage icon inside entries I get the following in the URL:
http://localhost:8888/http:/localhost:8888/http:/localhost:8888/about/locations/austin-tx

How can I change this to https://craftsite.test/about/locations/austin-tx like a normal URL? Where would I go to change these settings? MAMP and my .env file? I'm at a loss trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the **Entry URL Format** under `Settings > Sections > [choose section]`. If you want your URLs to mirror the Structure's hierarchy then set it to something like `{parent.uri}/{slug}`.

**However!** It looks to me like you're falling into the trap of mirroring the current design/layout of your front end site into your content model. I've inherited lots of sites built like this and they become practically impossible to [redesign/realign](https://alistapart.com/article/redesignrealign/), instead requiring full rebuilds, and they're just horrible to work with once the content model grows.

Instead, consider creating a separate section called "Locations" where each entry represents a single location, and then use relationships to tie everything together.

More comprehensive rant about arbitrary hierarchical abuse available at https://cld.agency/blog/content-utopia!

In short, I'd argue that semantically/taxonomically speaking, a child item in a hierarchy should always be a more specific type of its parent, but still the same "thing". "Austin TX" is not the same "thing" as the "Locations" entry, nor the "About" entry. I would imagine that the former should be a listing page showing all locations, while the latter should be a generic information page that gathers together whichever content the editor chooses.